# UserControl doesn't show validation exception in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, user-controls

I have a user control and I have bound its dependency property **TextValue** to a View Model **RightSpecGlassStrength**

**UserControl code**

```
<UserControl x:Class="NumericUpDown1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="25" d:DesignWidth="70">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <TextBox x:Name="InputTextBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                 Style="{StaticResource NumericUpDownTextBoxStyle}"
                 KeyDown="InputTextBox_KeyDown" 
                 KeyUp="InputTextBox_KeyUp"
                 GotFocus="InputTextBox_GotFocus" 
                 LostFocus="InputTextBox_LostFocus"  
                 MouseWheel="InputTextBox_MouseWheel"
                 MouseEnter="InputTextBox_MouseEnter"
                 TextInputStart="InputTextBox_TextInputStart"
                 LayoutUpdated="InputTextBox_LayoutUpdated"
                 />
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

**ViewItems.Xaml**

```
  <userControl:NumericUpDown1 x:Name="RightSpecGlassStrengthUpDown" Maximum="28" Minimum="-28" Step="0.25"  TextValue="{Binding RightSpecGlassStrength, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" TabIndex="5"   />
```

**ViewItemsViewModel.cs**

```
  public class ViewItemsViewModel : EntityViewModel
{

    #region constructor
    public ViewItemsViewModel(){}
    #endregion

    #region properties


    private Double rightSpecGlassStrength;
    public Double RightSpecGlassStrength
    {
        get
        {
            return rightSpecGlassStrength;
        }
        set
        {
            rightSpecGlassStrength=value;
            ValidateStrengths("RightSpecGlassStrength", RightSpecGlassStrength);
            PropertyChangedHandler("RightSpecGlassStrength");
        }
    }

    private void ValidateStrengths(string propertyName1, double RightSpecGlassStrength)
    {
        ClearErrorFromProperty(propertyName1);
        if (RightSpecGlassStrength == 0)
            AddErrorForProperty(propertyName1, "Value can not be 0");
    }


    #endregion
}
```

My **EntityViewModel.cs** is implementing *INotifyDataErrorInfo* interface and inherit *ViewModelBase* class

```
 public class EntityViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyDataErrorInfo
    {
      }
```

**ViewModelBase.cs** implements *INotifyPropertyChanged*

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
}
```

My code works fine when I bind the textbox or other silverlight control to the viewmodel.
and shows proper validation exception on the control.

But when the user control gets a validation exception the control does not show any exception.

I'm not getting whats wrong with user control.???

Comment: What do you mean by 'when the user control gets a validation exception'?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to fully debug the issue without the code behind for the user control, however, it seems to me that you have a dependency property on the code behind like this:

```
public static DependencyProperty TextValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextValue", typeof(string), typeof(NumericUpDown1), null)
```

You then seem to be using the TextInputStart, KeyDown, KeyUp events to capture changes to the underlying control. My hunch is that either:
  a) You're failing to update the TextValue property to the new value.
  b) Your code behind is interfering with the validation process.

I would suggest that, instead of code behind, you name the user control in the xaml; i.e.

```
<UserControl x:Class="NumericUpDown1" x:Name="View"> ... </UserControl>
```

Then bind the text value of the underlying TextBox directly to the dependency property, like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=TextValue, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" ... />
```

This should then allow the validation mechanism to proceed as normal.

Hope it helps.